# iOS - Get push token when the user activates push notifications from settings

Tags: ios, notifications, settings, push, token

I am developing a iOS app working with push notifications.
I am able to show the alert to make the user accept or not push notifications and also to catch those events. My goal is store the pushstoken into settings for other purposes.

The problem is that I am facing is when the user changes the push notification configuration in the settings menu.

If the user the first time accepts to receive notifications I can store the token successfully, but if the user declines and later in any other moment turns on the notifications from the settings i am not able to catch the token. I know that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is called only once the user accepts the first time and it comes with the device token as parameter, so as far as i know the only way to catch the device token is at that time.

The matter is that i need to check if the user has enabled or not those notifications so I have implemented successfully a method that triggers when applicationDidBecomeActive is called. It checks if notifications have been modified (Enabled/Disabled) in the settings menu.

My question is: Is possible to catch the push token if it has been enabled for the first time from the settings menu? If not, could you give me some advice?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know about NSUserDefault. You can save device token in NSUserDefault. And retrive device token from NSUserDefault when you need device token.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    NSString *deviceId = [[devToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    deviceId = [deviceId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    deviceId = [deviceId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setValue:[deviceId description] forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

    NSLog(@"Your token is: %@", [userDefaults valueForKey:@"DeviceToken"]);

}
```

**Step 2 :**

```
How to retrieve device token from NSuserDefault

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *deviceToken = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"DeviceToken"];

NSLog(@"my device token is : %@",deviceToken);
```

Comment: Yeah. I know what you mean.

The problem is that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken only is executed after the user allows the push notifications (and as you said correctly there I can save the token in NSUserDefaults). My problem is how obtian the token if the user do not allow push notifications (didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is no called and in didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError no token is passed as parameter) but latter allows the notifications in the settings menu.

Comment: @dabasa did you find a solution to this?